# Why is the query not being recognized?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

The code is to access a specific row within a column from a pgSQL table. I keep receiving an error that reads "You need to query() something first." However, I thought pgsql.query line would be enough to retrieve the value I am seeking. Other than that, this code seems to work.

```
int r;
```

...

```
//connect to database
if ( pgsql.connect() )
{
    //class submits query
    pgsql.query( "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER (" + str(r) + ") AS co2 FROM tree;" );
    //iterate r
    r++;  
    //return query value
    return( pgsql.getFloat("co2") );
}
else
{
    //disconnect from database
}
return(0)
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Does the unequal number of '(' and ')' in the query cause a problem?

Comment: processing... @a_horse_with_no_name I have cut the code to its essentials and it is iterating a query just fine in the console. However, the query submission isn't connecting.

Comment: That still doesn't tell us which programming language you are using (and what the `PostgreSQL` class is doing)

Comment: maybe it's just the code I pasted. the parentheses are equal in the code in the program.

Comment: the language is based from Java

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name http://bezier.de/processing/libs/sql/documentation/de/bezier/data/sql/SQL.html#query(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language this is, but the line in your example is missing a parentheses after the word tree - see my edit below

```
 "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER (" + str(r) + ") AS co2 FROM tree);"
```